# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from: l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_GAI_$_Dummy in GoogleAnalytics.o

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Unable to use Google Analytics SDK with use_frameworks! in objective c.

I am creating an objective c SDK and facing an issue that if I add the Google Analytics in my project and the parent app is having use_frameworks! enabled then I am not able to add the Google Analytics to my project.

However, I tried it by adding the GA SDK in parent app and then tried to use it then I get the following error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GAI", referenced from:       l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_GAI_$_Dummy in GoogleAnalytics.o